# Running Salome script without graphics

Tags: python, dump

I exported a script from Salome (dump), and I want to run it in python (I'm doing some geometric operation and I don't need any graphics). So I removed all the graphic command, but when I try to launch my python file, python cannot found the salome libraries.

I tried to export the salome path ('install_path'/appli_V6_5_0p1/bin/salome/) in PYTHONPATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH but it still doesn't work.

I also would like to know if it's possible to use only the geompy library without salome, and if it's possible, how can I install only the geompy library? ( I need to launch some geompy script on a UAV with only 8gb of memory, so the less thing I install, the better)

Answer (score 5):

I had similar wishes to you but after much searching I ended up concluding that what we both want to do is not completely possible.

In order to run a salome script on the command line without the GUI use

`salome -t python script.py` 
or simply
`salome -t script.py`

In order to run a salome script you must call it using the salome executable. It seems that you cannot use the salome libraries (by importing them into a python script that is then called with `python script.py`) without the compiled program. The executables that salome uses contain much of what the platform needs to do its job.

This frustrated me for a long time, but I found a workaround; for a simple example, if you have a salome script you can call the salome executable from within another python program with
`os.system("salome -t python script.py")`

But now you have a problem; salome does not automatically kill the session so if you run the above command a number of times your system will become clogged up with multiple instances of running salome processes. These can be killed manually by running killSalome.py, found in your salome installation folder. But beware! This will kill *all* instances of salome running on your computer! This will be a problem if you are running multiple model generation scripts at once or if you also have the salome GUI open.

Obviously, a better way is for your script to kill each specific instance of salome after it has been used. The following is one method (the exact paths to the executable etc will need to change depending on your installation):

```
# Make a subprocess call to the salome executable and store the used port in a text file:
subprocess.call('/salomedirectory/bin/runAppli -t python script.py --ns-port-log=/absolute/path/salomePort.txt', shell=True)

# Read in the port number from the text file:
port_file = open('/absolute/path/salomePort.txt','r')
killPort = int(port_file.readline())
port_file.close()

# Kill the session with the specified port:
subprocess.call('/salomedirectory/bin/salome/killSalomeWithPort.py %s' % killPort,shell=True)
```

EDIT: Typo correction to the python os command.

EDIT2: I recently found that problems with this method are met when the port log file (here "salomePort.txt" but can be named arbitrarily) is given with only its relative path. It seems that giving it with its full, absolute path is necessarily for this to work.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this is to be used to call the python script when attempting to run the script in the command window (these lines of code are not to be included in the script itself, correct?).  I tried running the os.command line in the command window and it returned an error saying the module "os" had no attribute "command".  Also, I tried running your last 10-line portion of code (and replaced "python script.py" in the second line with "python MyScriptName.py") and Python returned an error saying there was no file/directory "salomePort.txt".  Am I misunderstanding your answer?

Comment: @JohiasburgFrowell It should have said "os.system(...)", sorry! I will fix it... and regarding your questions:
The last bit of code should be in a separate script and if python cannot find the salomePort.txt file then you have to try and work out where it has been created on your system and direct it to the correct path. 
Good luck!

Comment: Hmm... I tried using `os.chdir('C:\\Users\\Me\\Desktop')` before the first `subprocess.call()` line (which should have directed the salomePort.txt file to be created on the desktop, correct?) and it did not appear on the desktop, and the same error about there not being a file/directory named salomePort.txt occurred.  The first command (`subprocess.call(...)`) did run, however.

Comment: @JohiasburgFrowell sorry I am not using Windows so I am not sure what is going wrong for you. I would try adding the full path for the file like this when creating it: 

    subprocess.call('c:\\salomedirectory\\bin\\runAppli -t python script.py --ns-port-log=c:\salomePort.txt', shell=True)

And, sorry, I am not sure how the Salome install paths look to the executable, the above may need to be modified accordingly.

Comment: I think I figured out my problem.  When the `subprocess.call(salome_path -t ....)` is run in Python,  Python immediately goes to the next step in the program (`open('salomePort.txt','r')`).  So basically, Salome is called, and while salome is being called (and has not yet defined a port to save to a text file), Python is already looking for the salomePort.txt file, which does not yet exist.  However, after a few seconds, Salome does save the salomePort.txt file, but not in time for the `open('salomePort.txt','r')` to be able to find it.

Comment: I see, that could be the case and I have certainly experienced similar problems before! Although it is not foolproof, a simple hack is then to pause the script for a while, say using

    `time.sleep(10)`

Comment: Yes, the pause seems to work OK as a temporary hack.  On another note, it seems that that particular instance of Salome being called is not being killed.  The `salomePort.txt` file was successfully created, and the rest of the script seems to run fine without returning any errors, but the instance of Salome that was just created at `salomePort` does not seem to get killed after use.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with salome on windows platform, use following

```
salome_folder\WORK>run_salome.bat -t script_file.py
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [Salome FAQ](http://www.salome-platform.org/user-section/faq/faq#_faq_004_07/%22Salome%20FAQ%22):

> To launch SALOME without GUI, use “`runSalome –t`” command: only the
>   necessary servers are launched (without GUI). To start an interactive
>   Python console then (for example, to be able to load TUI scripts), you
>   will need to use `--pinter` option

To launch Salome with only chosen modules:

> To launch a group of chosen SALOME modules, use the command “runSalome
>   –-modules=XXX,YYY”, where XXX and YYY are modules' names. You can use
>   –h command to display help of runSalome script.