# Error using numpy.loadtxt

Tags: python, numpy

I ran across this problem when trying to run code found in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28297834/4917819) answer to a question about loading Salome from a Python script (Salome is a 3D modeling program).  The part of the code relevant to my problem was in creating and re-opening a `.txt` file.  When attempting to open the file, I was getting an error that said there was no such file/directory as that file.

Then I tried just using `savetxt()` for just some random numpy array (with the directory being my desktop, acheived using `os.chdir()`), and no file was saved to my desktop, as far as I could tell.  Then, to test if the file had been created somewhere without me noticing, I tried using `loadtxt()` to find it, and I got the same error saying there was no file or directory named `MyFile.txt`.

Here's my code:

```
import os
import numpy as np

os.chdir('C:\\Users\\Brahm\\Desktop')
np.savetxt('stuff',npa([7,8]))
np.loadtxt('stuff.txt')
```

I also tried without quotation marks around `stuff` in the `savetxt` line

Is this a bug, or am I doing something incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your program, you are saving your array using -

```
np.savetxt('stuff',npa([7,8]))
```

The file name is `'stuff'` , not `'stuff.txt'` (Please note the difference). Then you are trying to load - `np.loadtxt('stuff.txt')` . This will not work, because you created file as - `stuff` , not `stuff.txt` .

Either store to `stuff.txt` using -

```
np.savetxt('stuff.txt',npa([7,8]))
```

**Or** load from `stuff` -

```
np.loadtxt('stuff')
```